# Bug in azure?, askes multifactor even that multifactor disabled

Tags: azure, multi-factor-authentication

In azure under `Azure Active Directory-->users-->Multi Factor Authentication` I disabeled the multifactor auth, but when I try to access from browser I'm still getting message to open the page via some message to my mobile phone.

Here is screenshot from azure settings:

[image]

Here is the error when I try to access from api:

> {"error":"interaction_required","error_description":"AADSTS50076: Due to a configuration change made by your administrator, or because you moved to a new location, you must use multi-factor authentication to access '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'.\r\nTrace ID: b59ca6c5-b9bc-4c68-a9a2-1e3ba6d2d300\r\nCorrelation ID: 14e59b18-d5ba-4a35-9623-5fad5e2351ec\r\nTimestamp: 2020-02-13 06:21:47Z","error_codes":[50076],"timestamp":"2020-02-13 06:21:47Z","trace_id":"b59ca6c5-b9bc-4c68-a9a2-1e3ba6d2d300","correlation_id":"14e59b18-d5ba-4a35-9623-5fad5e2351ec","error_uri":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=50076","suberror":"basic_action"}

---

here a screenshot `Azure Active Directory-->Security-->Conditional Access`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable multi-factor authentication:

1. Go to  [Azure Active Directory Properties](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/ActiveDirectoryMenuBlade/Properties) page.
2. On the bottom of the page, choose Manage Security defaults, and in the Enable Security defaults pane, set Enable Security defaults toggle to No.

[source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/admin/security-and-compliance/set-up-multi-factor-authentication?view=o365-worldwide)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if you are a global administrator, for example. They can be still required to undergo MFA.

Comment: how can I to disable the MFA?

Comment: check azure ad blade > security > conditional access > require MFA for admins

Comment: under "conditional access" do I need to create a new policy? I will add a screenshot because I can't see "require MFA for admins"